# might not be good VS might be not good

Tags: modal-verbs, negation, adverb-placement

I've been taught that when making a negative with a sentence with a modal verb in it, **not** should be placed right after the modal verb as in ***She might not be good.***

But I wonder how about another similar sentence below.

> She might be not good.

With **not** placed after *be*, to me it feels natural.
I'd like to get your answers about this.
Thank you.

Comment: No, it is not idiomatic.

Comment: No, that would be "She might be **no** good."

Comment: I can imagine the construction being used to contrast **good** with something else, as in: **She might be not (just) good but absolutely perfect for the job.** Here, the alternative placement of **not** doesn't work.

Comment: Agree with the comments above with one caveat - English is a very dynamic language and something being 'not good' is a usage that seems to be growing. Generally, it's used more in relation to situations than people, but it may be another one of those changes in-progress.

Comment: Thank you all for the informative comments.
@RonaldSole's comment contains an interesting case. English feels as dynamic as PerryW has pointed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would automatically respond with She might be not good* is incorrect you should say *She might not be good* or *She might be no good*

However in this situation even the dictionary has no really convincing argument that you are wrong just that it is not normally done that way.

> **We use no and not in some common fixed expressions:** [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/no-or-not)

> No problem, no good, not worth

> When you see Alan, can you give him this letter? Yes sure, **no problem**.

> It’s **no good** standing around watching. Do something!

> It’s **not worth** taking a taxi. We can walk.

But since you are referring to all modals;

> *She might be not good. With not placed after be, to me it feels natural*.

*Is not a convincing argument for the rest of the modal clan to be treated in the same way. It also has a somewhat colloquial or Pigeon English feel to it.*

Comment: Thank you very much for the kind answer.

I'd like to ask you a bit more about it.
Is *no* allowed to modify an adjective *good*, not a noun in the case of *no good* only because the case is one of some common fixed expressions?
How about *no sensitive*, *no rich*, or *no clever*?
I think all the other cases are allowed as long as the speaker intends to emphasize it.